# How to reset line numbers when importing from source file with minted

Tags: minted

I'm importing a portion of code from a source file with

```
\inputminted[firstline=22,lastline=41]{python}{file.py}
```

which gives :
[image]

However, I wish for the line numbers to be reset to 1 and I don't know what arguments I can use to do so. Any hint?

EDIT:

As suggested, adding `firstnumber=1` as an argument works.

```
\inputminted[firstnumber=1,firstline=22,lastline=41]{python}{file.py}
```

produces:
[image]

Comment: The `minted` manual mentions the option `firstnumber`: "Line number of the first line.". Probably adding `firstnumber=1` as in `\inputminted[firstline=22,lastline=41, firstnumber=1]{python}{file.py}` works?

Comment: yes! it did the trick! thanks!

Comment: Please, don't add the answer to your question --- have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minted` package documentation mentions the `firstnumber` key:

[image]

that accepts three possible values:

- `auto` is the default one and usually is equal to 1. If you use this im conbination with `firstline`, the line number of `firstline` will be used instead.
- `last` lets you continue the line numbering from the previous verbatim environment
- `integer` lets you specify the line numer of the first line.

Thus, using `\inputminted[firstnumber=1,firstline=22,lastline=41]{python}{file.py}` should result in the expected output.